# How can I use JSON data with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

This seems really simple but I've looked all over and I can't find any documentation for this.

I have the following json file:

```
//data.json
{
  "movie1": [
    {"name": "Inception"}
]}
```

and I just want to print the value of `name` with Ruby.

```
json = File.read('data.json')
data = JSON.parse(json)
data['movie1']['name']
```

But I'm getting the error

"no implicit conversoin of String into Integer"

How can I print `name`?

Comment: Viewing the result in ruby, e.g. `pp data` would give you clues as to the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"no implicit conversion of String into Integer" usually comes when you're trying to use an array as a hash. [`Array[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) expects an index (integer). Your data is a hash inside an array inside a hash :

You need :

```
data['movie1'][0]['name']
```

or

```
data.dig('movie1', 0, 'name')
```